# Что означает термин "бесхозные данные"?

Tags: данные

И как этот термин называется по-английски?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Термин `"бесхозные данные"` присутствует в переводе издательства "Питер" книги "Robert С. Martin The Clean Coder: A Code of Conduct for Professional Programmers" (РОБЕРТ МАРТИН ИДЕАЛЬНЫЙ ПРОГРАММИСТ как стать профессионалом разработки ПО, 2018 г.).
В оригинале этот термин звучит как "[Tramp](https://www.multitran.com/m.exe?l1=1&l2=2&CL=1&s=Tramp) Data", что можно назвать по-другому как "бродячие данные".

`Wiktionary` дает такое определение: ["Data which is passed via one function to another, and not otherwise used by the first"](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/tramp_data#:%7E:text=tramp%20data%20(uncountable),otherwise%20used%20by%20the%20first.). В Google-переводе это звучит как "Данные, которые передаются через одну функцию в другую и не используются первой".

Comment: Если я правильно понимаю суть, то это скорее правильнее было бы назвать "транзитными данными" )